# How to /testfor player in water

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command block mechanism that give a specific player named `PlaycastSteffen` the effect of speed speed level 11.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 1):

`/execute`'s `detect` mode will allow you to execute a command from an entity only if they succeed in finding a block. For example:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ water * /effect @a[c=1,r=0] speed 1 11
```

If you only want it to work for `PlaycastSteffen`, then you can do:

```
/execute PlaycastSteffen ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ water * /effect PlaycastSteffen speed 1 11
```